# Programatically created a new tab page that contains a web browser. How to make the tab page text be same as the web browser document title?

Tags: c#, winforms

So, the user will click a menustrip item. This will create a new tabpage in the tab control, that will contain a web browser and a textbox. How can I make the web browser's document title be the same as the tabpage text? This is my code:

```
private void newTabToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TabPage tabpage = new TabPage();
        tabpage.Text = "New Tab";
        tabControl1.Controls.Add(tabpage);
        WebBrowser webbrowser = new WebBrowser();
        TextBox textbox = new TextBox();
        textbox.Parent = tabpage;
        textbox.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
        webbrowser.Parent = tabpage;
        webbrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        webbrowser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
        webbrowser.Navigate("https://www.google.com");
    }
```

Tried:

```
tabpage.text = webbrowser.DocumentTitle;
```

and:

```
tabpage.text = webbrowser.DocumentTitle.ToString();
```

but didn't work. Well, it compiled but after I clicked the toolstripmenuitem it gave me an error.

Comment: ASP.NET? WebForms? Please add appropriate tags.

Comment: "It gave me an error" - so, did you read the error, or just go straight to stackoverflow?

Comment: Windows Forms Application.

Comment: "Unhandled exception has occured in your application". I don't think this can explain what problem it is.

Comment: There should be more details than that, especially if you're running it from visual studio.

Comment: Let me just debug it

Comment: Debugging it is what you should have done before asking on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Still no errors. When I write:
tabpage.text = webbrowser.DocumentCompleted.ToString();
and then I debug it, the tabpage text goes blank. It should go "Google" because the web browser navigates to Google

Comment: I would use the DocumentCompleted event from the web browser but I don't find it in the solution explorer because it is created programatically

Answer (score 0):

When you create your WebBrowser control, use the DocumentCompleted event to update the TabPage you created:

```
WebBrowser webbrowser = new WebBrowser();
webbrowser.DocumentCompleted += (s1, e1) => { tabpage.Text = webbrowser.DocumentTitle; };
```